# How to add an 'id' property to the HTML 'ul' tag generated by the jQuery Autocomplete widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) widget and I would like to add an `id` property to the HTML `ul` tag generated by the mentioned widget. That is, I would like to change the code from

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ..." role="..." style="...">...</ul>
```

to

```
<ul id="my_custom_id" class="ui-autocomplete ..." role="..." style="...">...</ul>
```

How can I make that in an easy and correct way?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: if you explain your end goals , there are likely easy ways to resolve using existing methods and callbacks

Comment: @epascarello - It is just because I am planning to perform some custom show / hide actions (or something else) on the `ul` element when on the same page are present *multiple* jQuery Autocomplete widgets.

Comment: can use the element class and target the visible one. I suspect you are goung to run into conflicts with the internal plugin show/hide

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the input in a div or another HTML element and show/hide the whole thing (the wrapper)? No need to tinker with innards that way, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete").attr("id", "my_custom_id");
var id = $("ul.ui-autocomplete").attr("id");
alert(id);
```